# Where to import tensorflow using ray actors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, python-import, ray

Using ray actors to run several tensorflow models in parallel, i ask myself where to import tensorflow:

```
# [1] maybe import tensorflow here?

@ray.remote(num_cpus=1)
class Remote_Runner:
    # [2] maybe import tensorflow here?
    def __init__(self, weights):
        # [3] maybe import tensorflow here?
        self.model=My_model()
        self.model.set_weights(wegihts)

    def do_something_with_model:
        self.model.do_something()
```

Example given in the documentation mentions to import tensorflow in the actor due to 'side-effects of importing TensorFlow and setting global state', but only gives an example of a ray remote function. So should i run 'import tensorflow as tf' at [1], [2], or [3], or even somewhere else? Is there a best practice to follow here, what are the differences between [1], [2] and [3], i.e. how do i access tensorflow in each case and when are they executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that this is fixed now, but the safest option to consider is importing tensorflow at [3].

Answer (score 1):

As per the Best Practices mention in https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/using-ray-with-tensorflow.html, its better to import tensorflow inside `My_model()`

you can consider below example

```
def create_keras_model():
    from tensorflow import keras
    from tensorflow.keras import layers
    model = keras.Sequential()
    # Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", input_shape=(32, )))
    # Add another:
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    # Add a softmax layer with 10 output units:
    model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.01),
        loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
        metrics=[keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy])
    return model
```

```
import ray
import numpy as np

ray.init()

def random_one_hot_labels(shape):
    n, n_class = shape
    classes = np.random.randint(0, n_class, n)
    labels = np.zeros((n, n_class))
    labels[np.arange(n), classes] = 1
    return labels


# Use GPU wth
# @ray.remote(num_gpus=1)
@ray.remote
class Network(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = create_keras_model()
        self.dataset = np.random.random((1000, 32))
        self.labels = random_one_hot_labels((1000, 10))

    def train(self):
        history = self.model.fit(self.dataset, self.labels, verbose=False)
        return history.history

    def get_weights(self):
        return self.model.get_weights()

    def set_weights(self, weights):
        # Note that for simplicity this does not handle the optimizer state.
        self.model.set_weights(weights)
```